# csrstub.exe keeps on appearing on UAC, should I allow it?

Tags: windows-7, uac

csrstub.exe keeps on appearing on the User Account control asking permission to run.

I got the feeling that his is a malware so I always select no, however it keeps on popping back again.

What is csrstub.exe anyway? Should I allow it?  how will I remove it from my computer?

it keeps on saying "Do you want to allow the Following Program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer"? 
Then the details; 
Program Name:  csrstub.exe 
Publisher: Unknown
Hard Drive on this computer

Then this keeps on popping up every 5 seconds

Comment: Can you tell us how come you know the program asking you permission is csrstub.exe?  Frow what I can gather from google it has nothing to do with User Account Control.  Please elaborate further if you wish to get help.

Comment: Edited the question sir

Comment: the exe has the following discretion: "allows lua to launch 16-bit applications". Do you try to run 16Bit software when this happens?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't know..what if it's harmful if I run it? and it does something irreversible?

Comment: run Procmon.exe in background and look which process triggers this exe run: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search it does seem that Csrstub.exe is a legitimate part of windows. However the fact that's it's causing UAC prompts & the publisher is unknown may well suggest it's malware named after the legitimate executable.

> This file is part of Microsoft® Windows® Operating System. Csrstub.exe is developed by Microsoft Corporation. It’s a system and hidden file. Csrstub.exe is usually located in the %SYSTEM% folder and its usual size is 47,616 bytes.

My first suggestion would be to open msconfig (WIN + R (open run) type **msconfig** and hit enter) Then browse to the start up tab and see if Csrstub.exe is listed there. If it is go ahead and check the location of the file, if it's different than in the quote above (especially if it runs from appdata/roaming or temp) browse to the location, check the file size against the quote above. If it's in a suspicious location or the file size is way off, I would go ahead and delete it. (single click, hold shift press delete) If you're unsure about anything let me know.

Comment: I think Shift + Delete is a little bit dangerous, if you don't know, what is it. At least, it can be useful to find csrstub.exe in your PC and upload it on https://www.virustotal.com/ to check, if it's a malware.

Comment: That's a fair point Dolmayan, however if it's a 25kb file in the temp folder for example, you don't need virustotal to tell you it's probably not something you want on your computer. It's worth pointing out if virustotal says something is clean, it doesn't necessarily mean it's true either. Script kiddies use similar sites daily to make sure their trojan.exe is FUD (fully undetectable) and isn't getting caught.

Comment: Additionally if the file is legitimately  "part of Microsoft® Windows®" it will not be shown in the msconfig start up tab. That is a usually trait of 3rd party programs (there are exceptions), like ones published by "Unknown", it being there in the first place is cause for alarm.

Comment: :) there are a lot of other places, where malware can be registered to run on system start and aren't visible in msconfig startup tab. Of course, file located in temp can be deleted safety, but a lot of malware are moving into %windir%\system32, also you can change data in VERSIONINFO to be "part of Microsoft® Windows®".
And 25KB is a lot.

Comment: You're right but let's not get ahead of ourselves here, as per my initial suggestion if something is in temp or appdata and is a ridiculous file size then we could probably stand to lose it. In my experience the msconfig start up tab is not a bad place to identify things that aren't what they claim to be. If the OP needs clarification not to delete something that is consistent with the quote I posted, consider this his clarification.